# AWS Deeplens with Keras and MXNet Model: ValueError for symbol 'data' not found

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, mxnet, aws-deeplens

I have a CNN model that I made using Keras using MXNet as the backend. I am able to create, train, and export a model without a hitch. However, when I attempted to load this model to the DeepLens, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: [91mYou created Module with Module(..., data_names=['data']) but input with name 'data' is not found in symbol.list_arguments(). Did you mean one of:
        /conv2d_1_input1
        conv2d_1/kernel1
        conv2d_1/bias1
        conv2d_2/kernel1
        conv2d_2/bias1
        conv2d_3/kernel1
        conv2d_3/bias1
        dense_1/kernel1
        dense_1/bias1
        dense_2/kernel1
        dense_2/bias1
        dense_3/kernel1
        dense_3/bias1[0m
```

I never made an argument for a symbol named `data`. All of the other symbols make sense because those were derived from my model. I have added all the code associated with Keras CNN creation below.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(8, (1,1), input_shape=inputShape))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(16, (1,1), padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (1,1), padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(240))

model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(120))

model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

Is there a way around this or a way to work with this using Keras with MXNet as the backend? Do I have to run a command on the Amazon Deeplens? Is there something I have to add into the model?

Answer (score 0):

Effectively the problem is that the default name of the input symbol in MXNet is `data`. In Keras it seems that the default name used for the input symbol is `/conv2d_1_input1`. 
You can two things:

- Rename the `/conv2d_1_input1` symbol in your `-symbol.json` file to `data`.
- I am not very familiar with how managed the deep lens is, but if you have access to the code that does: `Module(..., data_names=['data'])` replace it with `Module(..., data_names=['/conv2d_1_input1'])` like in this [tutorial](https://github.com/awslabs/keras-apache-mxnet/wiki/Save-MXNet-model-from-Keras-MXNet#import-the-model-in-mxnet-for-inference)